# Adding entire row using epplus in vb

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, epplus, epplus-4

I need to add a row in excel sheet before the last row in epplus. 
So far I got:

```
 ws.InsertRow(ds.Tables(0).Rows.count-1,1)
```

However this code adds a cell on Fist column. How do I add for entire columns? Is there any way to add a row for entire columns? how ?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your issue.  The InsertRow command as you show should have added a row at the end. From there you should be able to ws.Cells(1,s.Tables(0).Rows.count-1).Value = "whatever".  Syntax might be slightly off, doing from memory....  That would put whatever in the last rows, first column.

Comment: Thanks @klabranche ...

Comment: Uhhhhh!!  I was writing ugly code.... Just moved outside of loop for row fixed the problem!